# Pandas read_sql_query duplicates column names in cells in v2.0.0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In the latest version of pandas (v2.0.0)(Released 3rd April, 2023), the read_sql_query function does not seem to work.

I am using a pymssql connection and when executing a query, the result set is fetched and the number of rows are intact but the column names are duplicated in the cell values.

The functionality works as expected in the previous version - v1.5.3

Going back to the previous version is a way to go. But what else can be done to fix this?
Is this really a breaking change from pandas?

Code sample to reproduce the issue

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, database=db, as_dict=True, autocommit=True)

result_set = pd.read_sql_query("select * from table", conn)
print(result_set.head())
```

The result set looks like this with v2.0.0 (Unexpected Behavior)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Column A | Column B |
| Column A | Column B |

The result set looks like this with v1.5.3 (Expected Behavior)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

Installed version
python-3.10.5
pandas-2.0.0

Comment: *But what else can be done to fix this?*. You did the [right thing](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52437). Now, wait and use Pandas 1.5.3. Maybe you can try with `connectorx`

Comment: I guess I'll have to wait then. I am still surprised how something like this was missed during testing.